# Need Help for DATE_FORMAT( p.date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = CURDATE( )

Tags: mysql

I have a query for getting today's records from table. I have inserted the date field by using `now()`.

```
select u.*,p.* from user_brands as u inner join products as p where u.parent_id = p.cat_id and date_format( p.date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = curdate( )
```

By using this query every first time I am getting empty results, once if I refresh the page I am getting the results. Why is it not returning values for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler version is to use condition `DATE(p.date) = CURDATE()`. As for the empty first set, no idea. You mention that you refresh a page, does your query work in mysql command line or other non-web browser interface?

Answer (score 0):

try with this query:

```
select u.*,p.* from user_brands as u inner join products as p where u.parent_id = p.cat_id and YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(now()) and MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(now()) and DAY(p.date) = DAY(now())
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is working fine. But my doubt is  why i am getting the empty result set first time when im using date_format = curdate()